# UITapGestureRecognizer with arrangedSubviews

Tags: swift

i add about 20+ images to the stack and by tap on image i need to change borderColor, but with this code i have error " "-[__NSArray0 tapOnView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance "

Add stack here

```
private lazy var mainHStack: UIStackView = {
        let stack = UIStackView()
        stack.axis = .horizontal
        stack.distribution = .fill
        stack.spacing = 8
        return stack
    }()
```

Add constraints here

```
scrollView.addSubview(mainHStack)
        
        mainHStack.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.edges.equalToSuperview()
        }
tapOnMediaView()
```

Configure stack here

```
 func configureMediaViewer(withImages images: [String]) {
        for image in images {
            let imageView = UIImageView()
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 8
            imageView.clipsToBounds = true
            
            imageView.setImage(imageUrl: image)
            mainHStack.addArrangedSubview(imageView)
            
            imageView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
                make.width.height.equalTo(60)
            }
        }
    }
```

Check if i tapped on image here

```
func tapOnMediaView() {
        let arrangedImages = mainHStack.arrangedSubviews
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: arrangedImages, action: #selector(tapOnView))
        if let tag = tap.view?.tag {
        let currentImage = mainHStack.arrangedSubviews[tag]
        currentImage.layer.borderWidth = 1
        currentImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
        }
        addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }
```

TapOnView has a delegate

```
 @objc func tapOnView() {
        delegate?.tapOnView()
    }
```

Delegate

```
protocol PhotosViewProtocol: AnyObject {
    func tapOnView()
}
```

Extension for mainVC

```
extension MediaViewerViewController: PhotosViewProtocol {
    func tapOnView() {
        print("check if works")
//not works :C
    }
}
```

how do i change my code to get a result?

Comment: can you show func tapOnView  implementation and where youu have defined that ?

Comment: sure, i add it. It has delegate

Comment: ok so the issue here is the target object.
target object should be an object that would be recipient of action messages sent by the receiver when it recognizes a gesture.
refer to this doc [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/1624211-init)init(target:action:)

you should replace it with probably self or object of type which defines your selector view.